# Free Memory Reporting

Tags: linux, memory, ram

I have a system where we are constantly storing files into RAM (under /tmp/), processing them and then deleting them.

Some files we need to keep in RAM and other not.

My problem is that I want to report how much RAM is left that is useable to store files.

When I use "free" I may get a report that says:

```
free: 10000 (KB)
```

However when I run `cat /proc/meminfo` I get a different/more-meaningful story:

```
memfree:     10000 (KB)
Cached:     100000 (KB)
SwapCached:      0 (KB)
Active:      59000 (KB)
Inactive:    41000 (KB)
```

Ok, I have approximated/rounded the values for clarity.

From this post: [linux-inactive-memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305606/linux-inactive-memory), I can see that "inactive" memory is usable, and therefore - as far as I am concerned - it is free.

So I should be able to report 10000 KB + 41000 KB of free (well, ok not "free" free, but usable) memory.

Is there a command I can use (or some other method) whereby I can report the total "usable" memory?

I believe the total usable, as far as I understand it, is "free" + "inactive".

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `MemAvailable` in `/proc/meminfo`?

Comment: ah, no... but that does sound like what I want!! - I am using busybox  (embedded) Linux, so its a bit cut-down.

Comment: It's not quite what you want, because it gives the amount of memory usable *before* you hit swap; combined with the amount of inactive memory it would solve your problem. It's [provided by the kernel](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440), so Busybox doesn't enter the equation; but you do need a recent enough kernel (3.14 or later). Alternatively you can use the formula in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, but the kernel is probably quite old I'll need to dig out the version), but anyway its not there :(.   I did not see a formula in the linked question... which part do you mean? - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.14, the Linux kernel tracks how much memory is really available — *i.e.* allocateable without hitting swap, including reclaimable memory — in the `MemAvailable` entry in `/proc/meminfo`. This already includes reclaimable memory tracked as inactive, so there’s no need even to add that.

On older kernels you can use the formula given in the answer to [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440):

```
awk -v low=$(grep low /proc/zoneinfo | awk '{k+=$2}END{print k}') \
 '{a[$1]=$2}
  END{ 
   print a["MemFree:"]+a["Active(file):"]+a["Inactive(file):"]+a["SReclaimable:"]-(12*low); 
  }' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: Ah - I thought you meant the formula in the link in my question. Ok, yes you can parse the /proc/meminfo file. But are you sure about adding the "Active(file)", as far as I have read (and can put the links if needed) you can't necessarily claim the "active" memory as "usable"...